# Swing keyboard not responding

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen, keylistener

I'm using a KeyListener on a JFrame object which I set as FullScreenWindow, something like this code:

```
class Game{

private GraphicsDevice device;
...

public void run(){
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.addKeyListener(new MarioKeyListener());
device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
}

...
}
```

And it works fine if I just create a Game object in my main method and call run().
However I want to do this inside the mousePressed() function of a MouseAdapter which I added to another JFrame-s MenuItem. The result is that the program runs as normal but doesn't accept any keyboard input.

```
JMenu gamemenu = new JMenu("Game");
   JMenuItem newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
    newGame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    Game g = new Game();
    g.run();    
    }               
});
gamemenu.add(newGame);
```

I think My frame object is not in focus, but calling setFocusable(true) and requestfocusinwindow() did not help. 
If anyone knows whats wrong or how to fix this, help would be greatly appreciated...

Tomi

Comment: You should usually avoid KeyListeners and instead use Key Bindings. The Swing tutorials will show you how to use these and will tell you why they are better.

Comment: Yes I've read that many times on this site, thats what i'm going to do if i can't find a faster solution.

Comment: If you read about "key bindings" many times, then why don't you design your game properly from the start? Also, you don't use a MouseListener to handle a click on a menu item. The Swing tutorial also show you the proper way to do this. I suggest you read the tutorial and learn the basics first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29)..

> Requests that this Component get the input focus, *if this Component's top-level ancestor is already the focused Window.*

Are you checking the return value?  I suspect it is failing because the new window is not the focused component at the moment the method is called.

If that is the case, the answer might be found in similar fashion to the [dialog focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) strategy of adding a [`RequestFocusListener`](http://www.camick.com/java/source/RequestFocusListener.java) to the mix.

Comment: I have to use a JFrame which is a top level container therefore not a JComponent... What I'm trying to do is set up a new JFrame that gets keyboard focus.

Comment: Here's a download link for the source files: https://www.rapidshare.com/#!download|165|852289592|mario_keylistener_problem.rar|389

Comment: The relevant code is :                                     Mariogame - main class
GameWindow.run() - runs the fullscreen game
ConfigWindow -s constructor
ScreenManager.setFullscreen()
MarioKeyListener-keyboard input